# Javascript is running before page load.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to find a form with javascript in order to know whether to run a script or not. Here is my code:

```
var planSelectionForm = {
  pages: ["#selection", "#payment"],

  init: function(form) {
    // Don't initialize if the page does not have a new payment form
    if (form.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    var _ = this;

    $(window).on("hashchange", function() {
      if (_.pages.indexOf(window.location.hash) >= 0) {
        _.show(window.location.hash);
      }
    });

    window.location.hash = _.pages[0];
  },

  show: function(section) {
    section = section.replace("#", "");
    if (section === "") {
      section = "selection";
    }
  },
};

// Make the script work on the plan form
planSelectionForm.init($("form#new_account"));
```

I'm trying to load the form from the page in the initializer. but it always tells me that the form is not on the page. This is true because the javascript is running before the page is loaded. I think this has something to do with turbolinks but I'm not sure? If anybody has an idea that would be great: Here is my application.js

### Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require tooltip.min
//= require pickadate/picker
//= require pickadate/picker.date
//= require pickadate/picker.time
//= require simplemde
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're including the code you've posted using simple `script`tags, you must make sure it runs only as soon as the page is loaded completely. With jQuery you achieve this by invoking sth. like `$(window).on("load", function() {...YOURCODEHERE...})`. See more about this here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the line:

```
planSelectionForm.init($("form#new_account"));
```

in [turbolinks:load](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events) event:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
   lanSelectionForm.init($("form#new_account"));
});
```